# How can I eliminate cut-off

Tags: bjt, common-emitter

I have built a multistage bjt circuit. I got my gain to be around 40, but I cannot figure out how to eliminate the cut-off. The only values I can change are the resistor values (except the 50kOhm resistor), and I cannot change the configuration of the circuit. [image]
I cannot alter the input voltage.

Comment: Reduce the input signal amplitude. What do you expect with a gain of 40?

Comment: I think you actually have a gain of much more than 40, but the amplifier is clipping at 20 V p-p.  Reduce the input level until the output is not clipping, then measure the gain.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is called clipping, or sometimes compression, it happens when the output can no longer increase (or decrease) in line with the input because there's no range left. You've got a peak to peak signal of 20.1V, from a 24V rail, another clear sign that the amplifier is running out of dynamic range.

These seems like a homework style question, where you've been asked to change the values of the resistors in order to maximise the output without distorting the signal. Hence you can't change the configuation, or the input for the final answer.

So you've currently got two stage BJT amp, where you need a total gain of around 20V / 0.25V = 80 without any distortion. What you currently have is a lot of distortion.

I recreated your schematic in a simulator and got the same results. So you have far too much gain. In a BJT, what's important is how much current goes into the base, as this is directly linked to the size of the output (as the current is amplified, not the voltage). Looking at this setup, there are no resistors on the bases, only on the emitters. R4 and R5 directly influence the ammount of current flowing into the bases of Q1 and Q2. It's also quite common to do what you've done and add a capacitor in parralel with the emmiter resistor, but this is usually done in order to allow the AC signal to bypass the the emitter resistors - which are usually part of DC biasing the amp. In this specific example, a 10uF capacitor is in parrallel with R4, effectively shorting it. This means there is virtually no limit on the current flowing into the base of Q1, and as such the gain maxes out and the signal clips. Reduce the value of this capacitor to something like 1n, and the peak to peak output drops to 3.75V, or a gain of 15.

This kinda seems like a bad design to me, and I'm not really sure of the point of C3 without some other resistance to control the transistor base current. In any case, you have a simulator, at this point you can get your answer by trial and error, or reading a textbook if you have one. I got a peak to peak value of 16.4V with a few minutes fussing. I'm not going to share the values I used because a) it's probably a better learning experience to do it yourself and b) it's been nearly a decade since I looked at this circuit, and I'm 90% sure my values are garbage that just happen to work close to well enough. That being said -

Be sure to compare the voltage at all three terminals of a transistor, it can be iluminating as to where a problem is comming for.
For Q1, R5&6 controll the DC bias point, in conjunction with R4
R4 controlls the ammount of current that flows into the base, and hence affects the collector current.
The collector current, multiplied by the resistor R3 produces the output voltage, hence R3 also controls the gain.

Answer (score 0):

I eliminated the clipping at the waveform bottom by reducing the amplifier resistances.  [image: 2 transistors ampl]
There is normal severe distortion (the top of the waveform is squashed) due to the lack of negative feedback.

The input level from the 1st transistor was increased for the output to reach 20Vp-p.
Now you must adjust the Rc and Re of the 1st transistor and maybe re-bias it for its output to be 55mV peak as shown on my simulation:

OOPS, wrong transistor part number. You try fixing it.